# Django: how does allow_tags and short_description works?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

Basic way to do it in the `models.py`, an example:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    ...

    def custom_tag(self):
        return ('custom: %s' % self.title)
    custom_tag.allow_tags = True
    custom_tag.short_description = _("Custom Tag")
```

or, if inside file of `admin.py`;

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title', 'custom_tag', ...]
    ...

    def custom_tag(self, instance):
        return ('custom: %s' % instance.title)
    custom_tag.allow_tags = True
    custom_tag.short_description = _("Custom Tag")


admin.site.register(Foo, FooAdmin)
```

My question is, how does `allow_tags` and `short_description` works? and where I can find the relevant documentation?

I can't found it at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/) or also at [source code](https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking at the development version of the documentation. If you look at the one for [Django 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) (scroll down to "Deprecated since version 1.9") you'll see that they're removing the `allow_tags` option and replacing it with other ways of achieving the same thing. There are plenty of examples on how to use `short_description` though since it's not deprecated.

If you really want to see the source code, [here's the line where it gets the short description](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.10.5/django/contrib/admin/options.py#L777). Don't worry about the `allow_tags` since it's removed in 1.11 - it should now done automatically by marking string as safe using `mark_safe()`.

---

As a side note, you don't need to add the `custom_tag()` method in both places. The admin looks in both the model and the admin class for it so one is sufficient. If it's not going to be used outside the admin, I would recommend placing it inside the admin class and avoid making the model more complex.